Parent/Child relationships in Rust without lifetime pollution
I've got a reasonably complex app that is subdivided into a small number of reasonably complex, highly-interdependent structs.  Right now we just have Arcs and Weaks spread around pretty haphazardly.  I'd love to remove them, and assume there's a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, but haven't quite found a good solution yet.
All of the sub-parts in question have interior-mutability, so don't need to worry about mut here.  However, each of the sub-parts interact with each other through a central App that is instantiated at startup, and destroyed at shutdown.  The only exception to this is in integration tests, where multiple Apps might exist at the same time, and be destroyed before the runtime completes.
This was originally just a giant static/global singleton, which made things simple, but didn't work well for tests.
The current structure is (roughly) as follows:
struct App {
  things: ThingManager,
  stuff: StuffManager,
  actions: ActionManager,
}
impl App {
  fn new() -> Arc<App> {
    // App instantiates each of the Thing/Stuff/Actions, and gives them a weak reference to itself
    let app = Arc::new(App { ThingManager::new(), StuffManager::new, ActionManager::new() })
    app.things.set_app(&app)
    app.stuff.set_app(&app)
    app.actions.set_app(&app)
  }
}

// Each of the Manager's look like:
struct ThingManager {
  app: OnceCell<Weak<App>>,
  // Other fields
}
impl ThingManager {
  fn set_app(&self, app: &Arc<App>) {
    self.app.set(Arc::downgrade(app))
  }
  fn get_app(&self) -> Arc<App> {
    self.app.get().upgrade()
  }

  // And unfortunately touch other parts of the app
  fn complex_logic(&self) {
    let app = self.get_app();
    let some_stuff = app.stuff.find_specific_stuff();
    let action = app.action.do_something(some_stuff);
    // etc
  }
}

I've looked into using things like arena allocators (bumpalo, generational-arena), but every time I start implementing I end up polluting my structs with <'app> lifetimes, and they very quickly spread everywhere in the code (lots of functions take an App, and need the lifetimes specified, etc).
I know my ThingManager will live exactly as long as my App, and when App is dropped, I'd like to drop the managers as well, how do I represent this cleanly?  I'm not super excited to use unsafe blocks, but if they were limited in scope (manual setup/teardown) and were "safe" assuming my constraints were maintained (Managers won't outlive an App, etc), I wouldn't be too opposed...

What exactly is wrong with the code you show? Although it's not really Rust-y, it seems fine and working to me.

In profiling, a huge amount of time is being spent in atomic operations from (I assume) the Arc upgrade/drop.  With the amount of interdependency between pieces, calling something on ThingManager does a get_app() does something small with it, calls StuffManager which does its own get_app(), and chains a large number of times (and then drops a large number of Arc<App> at the end of the chain).  In theory we could just have an &App, or (something like) a single Arc<App> in each Manager, so we dont have to upgrade/drop on every function call...

Ah, I see. I feel that indeed the architecture you are trying to do here is hard to achieve in Rust.
I'm not sure if the way you are splitting is the wisest, to be honest, for me the words "subdivided" and "highly interdependent" are contradicting each other. If you subdivide something, it shouldn't be highly interdependent, because in the end, you don't gain anything. It looks like you structured the code, but if it's really that interdependent, you cannot update one part without touching the other, so you can as well merge them.

Of course I understand that your example is highly minimized, so I'm not sure how valuable this advice is for your real project.

Another solution also commonly used in C++ is something called dependency injection. The trick is that you don't store dependent objects in the class, but pass them into functions at function calls using interfaces. This doesn't only solve this problem, but also makes the interfaces between your parts mockable, so they can be tested on their own. This is crucial; a unit should be testable by itself, otherwise there's no point having it be a unit. The disadvantage is that it adds a little complexity to the API of your managers.

In the end, the most important question I would ask myself is: is there any way to restructure the code so that your struct dependencies become a tree? Any kind of circular dependency chain is problematic and hard to maintain in general.

Yep, completely agree on the contradiction on subdivided/interdependent, its definitely the root of the problem here.  I've used dependency injection in the past, but unfamiliar with it within rust.  But you've sort-of hit at an interesting piece of this, which is that my App is essentially just acting as a dependency-injection tool as it is (albeit an ugly one)...

Some of the confusion in the post might be with calling things Manager, they're probably closer to just a regular dependency.  Imagine one of them is a DbConnection, one is a Cache, one is a WorkerThread, etc.  The WorkerThread might need a DbConnection, the DbConnection might cache things, the WorkerThread might look at the (same) cache as well, etc.  My immediate guess (with no data...) is that a dep-injection tool is going to use the same Arc structure under the hood, but I'll definitely look around and test a bit.

If you are multi-threaded, you actually need this complexity because threads can live longer than main, and rust prevents anything like this to avoid undefined behavior (Rust is guaranteed free of undefined behavior as one if its main objectives).
If you have only a single thread that does the upgrade, you can use Rc/Weak instead, which has much less overhead.

Yep, some of the complexity is definitely due to the multithreading (and how the Arcs originally got in there).  And completely understand the nature of threads/data living past main.  In this particular case though, I'm unsure how to explain to rust "I understand the implications here, I'll make sure this lives as long as you need", and take the UB risk associated with it.  Maybe I just suck it up and sprinkle some unsafe/raw-pointers around

Another note on the split/interdependent thing you mentioned, is at the end of the day, all of these Managers under the App are really part of the App, they're all the same object.  The splitting was only for code cleanliness purposes (common/similar code, having .get() on a Db be different than .get() on Cache, but the same function name).  Not sure how to reconcile that here, but essentially I want all of those sub-pieces to be a small part of the larger object (and thus lifetimes), I just don't know how to accomplish that in rust cleanly...

(Split due to length)  I'd normally say "Oh, instead of sub-structs, each part could just be a Trait on App (DbTrait, CacheTrait, etc), but there's some nice encapsulation in CacheTrait has its own fields (maps, lists, etc) instead of having them all top-level in App.  Perhaps App has a Cache (dumb struct), and a CacheTrait that only accesses that one struct?

"and take the UB risk associated with it" - you don't. That would defeat the entire purpose of using Rust. Even unsafe isn't meant for "just do it" scenarios, but instead means "I, the programmer, guarantee that I uphold the rules of soundness manually". 'Taking risks' just means that Rust as a programming language might be the wrong tool for the job :/

That said, not all multi-threaded programs need Arc. std::thread::scope works fine with normal references without any overhead. std::thread::scope tells the Rust compiler that the given thread will end before its enclosing scope (like main), weakening some of the defensive behavior of the compiler. You just need to restructure your program accordingly, I'm afraid. Although I still think that having bi-directional references is a red flag and there must be better ways to structure your code.

Completely agree on not just throwing unsafe around.  99.9% of the codebase I think rust is the right choice (for safety concerns), however just having issues at essentially the top/bottom of the application (startup/teardown).  Instead of "take the UB risk" I probably should have said "I'll make sure these two things live long enough for each other".

Sadly I'm unsure how to help you further without knowing more about your project, which would be out of scope for StackOverflow. Maybe ask in the Rust forum or Rust subreddit with more project-specific information?

I appreciate all the help and allowing my to bounce some ideas off of you.  I'll play around with a few ideas and see what I come up with.  Thanks!

If the only usage of multiple App s is in tests, then perhaps leaking is acceptable? In which case, you can just have Arc<App> instead of Weak<App>.

I don't know your use-case in detail but it looks like the following design may be a reasonable one:
struct App {
  things: ThingManagerInner,
  stuff: StuffManagerInner,
  actions: ActionManagerInner,
}
impl App {
  fn new() -> App {
    App {
        things: ...,
        stuff: ...,
        actions: ...,
    }
  }
  fn things(&self) -> ThingManager<'_> {
    ThingManager { app: self }
  }
}

// Each of the Manager's look like:
struct ThingManagerInner {
  // Other fields
  other_field: usize,
}
struct ThingManager<'a> {
    app: &'a App,
    // optionally add other references here as necessary if they are conditional based on app, deeply nested, inside a Vec...
}
impl Deref for ThingManager<'_> {
    type Target = ThingManagerInner;
    fn deref(&self) -> Self::Target {
        &self.app.things
    }
}
impl ThingManager<'_> {
  // And unfortunately touch other parts of the app
  fn complex_logic(&self) {
    let some_stuff = self.app.stuff().find_specific_stuff(self.other_field);
    let action = self.app.action().do_something(some_stuff);
    // etc
  }
}

In Rust, you usually want to orient your struct construction around data rather than behavior.
One can then construct behavior layers on top.
As a rule of thumb, you don't need unsafe for anything (besides FFI), and it's generally more a footgun than anything else, given the additional guarantees that one has to provide when writing unsafe in Rust compared to C (aliasing because of noalias optimizations, covariance/invariance,contravariance...) and the fact that there's always just a better design that preserves maximum performance while staying fully safe.

I do think this is roughly what I was looking for  (without being able to explain it).  Essentially just having a very thin wrapper around the underlying struct that tacks on an App when needed.  Thanks!
